# How to get minimum subgraph for given vertices?

Tags: python, neo4j, graph-databases, titan

I have a graph. I want to extract a subgraph containing nodes in a list as well as the other nodes that are linked to the nodes in the list.

Example: a graph has 4 nodes: 1,2,3,4 with the edges 1-2, 2-3, 1-4, 3-4. If my list has node 1,4, then the subgraph should be 1-2, 1-4 and 3-4

Is there a function in python libraries like py2neo for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For neo4j, you can use [Cypher queries](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-query-lang.html) to extract subgraphs from your database.  You can just use the `MATCH` clause of a query to express the pattern you're looking for.

In python, you'd probably use [py2neo](http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html) to run the cypher queries.  Here, I'll assume that the list of nodes you have are node IDs.  You might do something like:

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph()
targets = [1,4]
for target in targets:
    results = graph.cypher.execute("MATCH (n {id: %d})-[:foo]->(otherNode) RETURN n, otherNode" % target)
    # process results
```

One thing to watch out for.  Your graph specified that 1 is connected to 4, but so is 3.  This would actually make that connected subgraph component 1-3-4, not 1-4 and 3-4.  Because you specified it that way, note the match I did above just gives you one hop from the node you're searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it using Gremlin.

If you want to get your result as a tree:

```
gremlin> g.v(1,4).both().tree().cap().next()
==>v[1]={v[2]={}, v[4]={}}
==>v[4]={v[1]={}, v[3]={}}
```

Or, if you prefer a real subgraph, use the [recipe from the GremlinDocs](http://gremlindocs.com/#recipes/subgraphing):

```
gremlin> sg = new TinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> goc = { v, g ->
gremlin>   g.getVertex(v.id) ?: g.addVertex(v.id, ElementHelper.getProperties(v))
gremlin> }
==>groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@5118388b
gremlin> g.E().filter { it.bothV().retain(g.v(1,4).toList()).hasNext() }.sideEffect {
gremlin>  sg.addEdge(it.id, goc(it.outV.next(), sg), goc(it.inV.next(), sg), it.label,
gremlin>      ElementHelper.getProperties(it))
gremlin> }.iterate()
==>null
gremlin> sg.V()
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
==>v[4]
gremlin> sg.E()
==>e[0][1-link->2]
==>e[2][1-link->4]
==>e[3][3-link->4]
```

I'm not familiar with Python libraries, but I guess it's pretty much only copy & paste if you're using [Bulbs](http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/gremlin/).